# Set a particular group item at end in Navigation Drawer menu

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, menuitem

okay, **Google Keeps-Notes and Lists** App have a navigation drawer like this,
[Google Keeps-Notes and Lists App Navigation Drawer(Original)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZXWdc.jpg)

- I want to do same exact as I mention in this image. [I want this
  'EDIT'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vsHuq.jpg)
- I want that **EDIT** (the TextView) at right side of navigation drawer.
  I achieved this far,[My Navigation Drawer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoGKO.jpg)

  ```
   <group>
   <item android:title="LABALS"
       android:actionLayout="@layout/main_nav_drawer_edit">
       <menu>
           <item
               android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_lable"
               android:title="Label 1" />

           <item
               android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_create_new_label"
               android:title="Create new label" />
       </menu>
   </item>
  ```

what should I do to achieve this, Is it possible?

Comment: Please don't tag questions with the android-studio tag just because you use it: the Android Studio tag should **only** be used when you have questions about the IDE itself, and not any code you write (or want to write) in it. See [when is it appropriate to remove an IDE tag](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/315196/6296561), [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/354427/6296561), and [the tagging guide](/help/tagging). Use [android] or other relevant tags instead.

Comment: oh sorry for that, I don't again.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom `View` and apply to the `app:actionLayout` attribute of your `<item>`.

Comment: nah, I already tried it, It only work with individual items in menu. I have one <group> in menu. in that <group> there is <item> for title, in that title <Item> their is <menu> and inside that <menu> all navigation drawer <Item> exits. you can see in upper code. (if already solve this then please post a code)

Comment: @Jay Kundaliya Then just make that `<item>` look like a "group" label by using custom `View`. And don't forget the divider.

Answer (score 0):

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/grp_labeled"
    android:title="LABALS"
    app:actionLayout="@layout/main_nav_drawer_edit">
    <menu>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_lable"
            android:title="Label 1" />

        <item
            android:id="@+id/navigation_drawer_create_new_label"
            android:title="Create new label" />
    </menu>
</item>
```

layout:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="EDIT"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
```

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

like this?